# Install Ultimate edition IntelliJ plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have Ultimate edition of IntelliJ Idea w/ a valid licence. There is a very useful plugin only available in full edition named [Database Tools and SQL support](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/database_tools.html) that allows the developer to browse and run queries on sqlite database stored in phone.

Now i need to use this plugin in Android Studio, looks like Android Studio is based on community edition and does not have this plugin built-in, it's not available in plugin repositories too.

Is there any way to use IntelliJ Idea plugins in android studio? Just copy and pasting files in `plugins` folder doesn't seem to work.

[image: Plugins page screen shot]

I installed `Database Navigator` plugin but it cannot connect to android device like IntelliJ does. It there an alternative plugin to `Database Tools and SQL support` or any way to config `Database Navigator` so it can access databases inside android applications installed on mobile devices?

Comment: AFAIK, Android Studio's features are merged back into IntelliJ, did you try using Ultimate Edition with Android plugin?

Comment: @Vic Yes i normally use IntelliJ w/ android plugin, there is one specific project that i have to use Android Studio for and i need this plugin for this project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you stated, some plugins are only available in IntelliJ Ultimate, hence you cannot use them in IntelliJ Community, which Android Studio is based on. This is noted in the `plugin.xml` of the Database plugin:

```
<depends>com.intellij.modules.ultimate</depends>
```

That's why simply moving the plugin lib files won't help.

A solution would be to use both applications: Android Studio for coding and IntelliJ Ultimate to browse the phone database.

Comment: Good answer. I wonder though whether the dependency is purely logical or whether there is some actual code dependency on ultimate. What happens if the `plugin.xml` edited to remove this dependency?

Comment: Surprisingly, this *does* enable the plugin in CE. However, it's unusable. You can add a data source, but it's impossible to open either the table editor or the query console. Editor support is also broken.